# Matrix multiplication by specific amount

Tags: r

I need to create matrix 100x100 and multiply by 2 every record bigger then 5000 and I'm giving up :/

Code for matrix

```
m <- matrix(1:10000, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Can you make the example a bit smaller

Comment: Don't understand "multiply by 2 every record bigger then 5000"... can you show what do you mean?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code solve your problem:

```
m[m > 5000] = 2*m[m>5000]
```

Also:

```
m = ifelse(m > 5000, 2*m, m)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro!

Comment: To keep the `dim` attribute you must do `m[] = ifelse(etc)`. Upvote for the first code line.

Answer (score 0):

`n <- apply(m, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 5000, x*2, x))`